# Using R.string.<string-name> dynamically

Tags: java, android

My app uses a single activity to load multiple different contents by the user choice. If the user presses `recipe1` button from a Recyclerview from the *main activity* it should start the *recipes activity* and load the details matching this specific recipe.

Since I don't want to create an activity for each recipe, I need to load the details dynamically. The main activity starts the recipe activity with an intent containing the recipe name, e.g. `recipe1`, and using this data I want to load the details from my `strings.xml` file, e.g. `cooking_time_recipe1`, `ingredients_recipe1` and so on.

I found the function `getIdentifier()` and it works perfectly, although Android Studio shows a warning:  `Use of this function is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations and compile-time verification of code. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier (e.g. R.foo.bar) than by name (e.g. getIdentifier("bar", "foo", null)).`

Is there any way to avoid using this function?

I can write a function that recieves a recipe name and retrieves all its details' names from the `string.xml`, i.e.

input: `recipe1`, output: `cooking_time_recipe1, ingredients_recipe1, ...`

although I couldn't find a way to avoid the finding process of the id. I could manually maintain a HashMap to match strings to ids but I was thinking `getIdentifier()` is probably using a HashMap anyway, so no use to implement the same thing myself but not sure.

The adapter code (excluding the ViewHolder subclass):

```
public class RecipesViewPagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipesViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<String> recipes;

public RecipesViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> recipes) {
this.context = context;
this.recipes = recipes;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_recipes_pager, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CardTriplet currentRecipes = recipes.get(position);
    holder.cardRecipe1.setOnClickListener(view -> onCardClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(), 0));
    if (currentRecipes.get(1) != null) {
        holder.textRecipe2.setText(currentRecipes.get(1).getName());
        holder.cardRecipe2.setOnClickListener(view -> onCardClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(), 1));
    } else {
        holder.cardRecipe2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    if (currentRecipes.get(2) != null) {
        holder.textRecipe3.setText(currentRecipes.get(2).getName());
        holder.cardRecipe3.setOnClickListener(view -> onCardClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(), 2));
    } else {
        holder.cardRecipe3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Recipes.size();
}

private void onCardClick(int tripletNumber, int cardNumber) {
    Card card = Recipes.get(tripletNumber).get(cardNumber);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecipeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", card.getName());
    context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And the main activity gets the recipes for the adapter with:

```
String[] recipeNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.string.recipes)
```

And initializes the `ArrayList<CardTriplet> recipes` by looping over the `recipeNames` array and putting the values in `CardTriplet` objects

Comment: Take the warning for what it is: a warning. Understand what they are saying, and realise that "normally" you'd not do it this way. I think for what you are trying to do, this is a perfectly valid approach. A good naming convention for these related strings would be very helpful to decide on early.

Comment: I would also suggest, for maintainability, that you consider moving these dynamic strings into a separate strings resource file; your normal strings in `strings.xml` and these ones in something like `recipe_details.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your problem, you have several options:

1. Pass all data you need on the `RecipeActivity` in Intent. Not only recipe name. Something like this:

   ```
   val intent = Intent(activity, RecipeActivity::class)
   intent.extras = Bundle().apply {
       KEY_NAME = R.string.recipe_name
       KEY_COOKING_TIME = R.string.recipe_cooking_time
       ...
   }
   ```

In this case you can also **create a Data class** (if you use Kotlin) which implements Parcelable, and put just this Parcelable to intent.

2. Put the recipe id in Intent and create some `RecipesProvider` which will return strings by id of a recipe:

   ```
    class RecipesProvider {

        fun getCookingTimeById(id: Int) {
            when (id) {
                R.string.recipe_1 -> return ...
                else -> return ...
            }
        }

    }

    class RecipeActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

        private val recipesProvider = RecipesProvider()

        override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
            ...
            cookingTimeTextView.text = recipesProvider.getCookingTimeById(intent?.extras?.getInt(RECIPE_ID))
        }

    }
   ```

**Update:**
I'm not sure that the approach you're using with string array is valid, because it's really confusing to lean to text which is stored there and build some logic based on these strings.

Why don't you create some class `Recipes` which will contain the list with all recipes?

```
object Recipes {
    private val recipes = listOf(
        Recipe(
            name = R.string.recipe1_name,
            cookingTime = R.string.recipe1_cooking_time,
            .....
        )
    )

    fun getRecipe(position: Int): Recipe {}
}
```

And then you can rewrite your adapter like this:

```
public class RecipesViewPagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipesViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ....

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Recipes.Companion.size();
    }

    private void onReceiptClick(int adapterPosition) {
         Receipt receipt = Recipes.Companion.getRecipe(adapterPosition)
         // Start activity with this receipt
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this works passing the ids in the intent, but there is still a problem: The recipe names are also stored in the `strings.xml`. So when I load the `RecyclerView` with the recipe names it loads it from the `strings.xml`. So I can't actually find the ids without `getIdentifier()`, and hence can't pass them in the intent.

Comment: If you will attach the code of your Adapter and Activity it will help.

Comment: It works and if implemented as array can actually be `O(1)` W.C to find the id so might be worth the extra coding